# Hive: Subtracting months from a timeframe

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a time frame of 2017-2-1 (in yyyy-m-d format). I need to look backward to 12 months in my where statement. So, the answer should be like: 2016-2-1;
I tried with

`where previous_date= add_months('2017-2-1', -12)`

But, seems like, I am getting empty output. However, I do have data for

```
previous_date= '2016-2-1'
```

Is there any way to subtract a certain amount months by not using add_months? Or, am I missing something while using add_months statement? 
I don't want to subtract 365 days. Because, this could give me wrong output for a leap year.

Comment: I suspect that you are storing the dates as strings.  If so, use YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: use `add_months('2017-02-01', -12)` instead. the string format that would be recognized is `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: It should work. Show us some sample data and its data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because after apply add months, you get a string in for yyyy-MM-dd. Since Hive 1.2, you can you date_format UDF like this

```
select date_format(add_months('2017-2-1', -12), 'yyyy-M-d');
```

so your where clause should look like

```
where previous_date= date_format(add_months('2017-2-1', -12), 'yyyy-M-d')
```